# (offlineimap) Email directory still empty after successful connection; force methods don't make any difference

Tags: email, imap, offlineimap

i have newly installed offlineimap, but after the first start my maildirectory is still empty. Furthermoore, the methods described here http://offlineimap.org/doc/FAQ.html#can-i-force-offlineimap-to-sync-a-folder-right-now don't make any difference. I use the newest stable Version.

Have I forgotton something?

Regards

```
% offlineimap
OfflineIMAP 6.5.7
  Licensed under the GNU GPL v2+ (v2 or any later version)
Account sync main:
 *** Processing account main
 Establishing connection to imap.kolabnow.com:993
Enter password for account 'mainRemote':
 *** Finished account 'main' in 0:08
 Next refresh in 1.0 minutes

% offlineimap -d maildir 
OfflineIMAP 6.5.7
  Licensed under the GNU GPL v2 or any later version (with an OpenSSL exception)
Debug mode: Forcing to singlethreaded.
Now debugging for maildir: Maildir repository debugging
Now debugging for : Other offlineimap related sync messages
Account sync main:
 [maildir]: MaildirRepository initialized, sep is '.'
 *** Processing account main
 Establishing connection to imap.kolabnow.com:993
Enter password for account 'mainRemote': 
 [maildir]: _GETFOLDERS_SCANDIR STARTING. root = /home/[username]/maildir, extension = None
 [maildir]:   toppath = /home/[username]/maildir
 [maildir]:   dirname = 
 [maildir]: _GETFOLDERS_SCANDIR RETURNING []
 []: Copying folder structure from mainRemote to mainLocal
 *** Finished account 'main' in 0:09
```

`% pkill -⁠USR1 offlineimap`

```
% offlineimap -⁠u blinkenlights
[Connection successful etablished]
[Next sync in 1:00[

1: [active]      *Control: @
0: [active]          main: @
```

`% ls maildir`

my .offlineimaprc:

```
[general]
accounts = main

[Account main]
localrepository = mainLocal
remoterepository = mainRemote
synclabels = yes
autorefresh = 1
quick = 10

[Repository mainLocal]
type = Maildir
localfolders = ~/⁠maildir/


[Repository mainRemote]
ssl = yes
sslcacertfile = /⁠etc/⁠ssl/⁠certs/⁠ca-⁠bundle.crt
type = IMAP
remotehost = imap.kolabnow.com
remoteuser = bluemorpho@kolabnow.com
holdconnectionopen = yes
keepalive = 60
```

this .offlineimap makes also no difference

```
[general]
accounts = main

[Account main]
localrepository = mainLocal
remoterepository = mainRemote
synclabels = yes
#autorefresh = 1
#quick = 10

[Repository mainLocal]
type = Maildir
localfolders = ~/maildir


[Repository mainRemote]
ssl = yes
sslcacertfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
type = IMAP
remotehost = imap.kolabnow.com
remoteuser = bluemorpho@kolabnow.com
holdconnectionopen = yes
keepalive = 60
```

**EDIT**

```
% offlineimap -d imap
OfflineIMAP 6.5.7
  Licensed under the GNU GPL v2 or any later version (with an OpenSSL exception)
Debug mode: Forcing to singlethreaded.
Now debugging for imap: IMAP protocol debugging
Now debugging for : Other offlineimap related sync messages
Account sync main:
 [imap]: Using authentication mechanisms ['GSSAPI', 'CRAM-MD5', 'PLAIN', 'LOGIN']
 *** Processing account main
 Establishing connection to imap.kolabnow.com:993
 [imap]:   27:13.11 Account sync main imaplib2 version 2.43
 [imap]:   27:13.11 Account sync main imaplib2 debug level 5, buffer level 3
imap.kolabnow.com writer:
 [imap]:   27:14.21 imap.kolabnow.com writer starting
imap.kolabnow.com reader:
 [imap]:   27:14.21 imap.kolabnow.com reader starting using poll
Account sync main:
 [imap]:   27:14.21 Account sync main _request_push(continuation, None, {}) = HMOO0
 [imap]:   27:14.21 Account sync main None:HMOO0.ready.wait
imap.kolabnow.com handler:
 [imap]:   27:14.31 imap.kolabnow.com handler starting
imap.kolabnow.com reader:
 [imap]:   27:14.36 imap.kolabnow.com reader poll => [(4, 1)]
 [imap]:   27:14.36 imap.kolabnow.com reader rcvd 203
 [imap]:   27:14.36 imap.kolabnow.com reader < * OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ ID ENABLE MUPDATE=mupdate://mupdate.mykolab.com/ AUTH=LOGIN AUTH=PLAIN SASL-IR] imapf01.mykolab.com Cyrus IMAP Murder 2.5.2.3-Kolab-2.5.2-3.el6.kolab_14 server ready\r\n
imap.kolabnow.com handler:
 [imap]:   27:14.36 imap.kolabnow.com handler _put_response(* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ ID ENABLE MUPDATE=mupdate://mupdate.mykolab.com/ AUTH=LOGIN AUTH=PLAIN SASL-IR] imapf01.mykolab.com Cyrus IMAP Murder 2.5.2.3-Kolab-2.5.2-3.el6.kolab_14 server ready)
 [imap]:   27:14.36 imap.kolabnow.com handler untagged_responses[OK] 0 += ["[CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ ID ENABLE MUPDATE=mupdate://mupdate.mykolab.com/ AUTH=LOGIN AUTH=PLAIN SASL-IR] imapf01.mykolab.com Cyrus IMAP Murder 2.5.2.3-Kolab-2.5.2-3.el6.kolab_14 server ready"]
 [imap]:   27:14.36 imap.kolabnow.com handler untagged_responses[CAPABILITY] 0 += ["IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ ID ENABLE MUPDATE=mupdate://mupdate.mykolab.com/ AUTH=LOGIN AUTH=PLAIN SASL-IR"]
 [imap]:   27:14.36 imap.kolabnow.com handler state_change_free.set
 [imap]:   27:14.36 imap.kolabnow.com handler _request_pop(continuation, (False, '* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ ID ENABLE MUPDATE=mupdate://mupdate.mykolab.com/ AUTH=LOGIN AUTH=PLAIN SASL-IR] imapf01.mykolab.com Cyrus IMAP Murder 2.5.2.3-Kolab-2.5.2-3.el6.kolab_14 server ready')) = HMOO0
 [imap]:   27:14.36 imap.kolabnow.com handler None:HMOO0.ready.set
Account sync main:
 [imap]:   27:14.36 Account sync main _get_untagged_response(OK) => ['[CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ ID ENABLE MUPDATE=mupdate://mupdate.mykolab.com/ AUTH=LOGIN AUTH=PLAIN SASL-IR] imapf01.mykolab.com Cyrus IMAP Murder 2.5.2.3-Kolab-2.5.2-3.el6.kolab_14 server ready']
 [imap]:   27:14.36 Account sync main state => NONAUTH
 [imap]:   27:14.36 Account sync main [async] CAPABILITY ()
 [imap]:   27:14.36 Account sync main state_change_pending.acquire
 [imap]:   27:14.36 Account sync main state_change_pending.release
 [imap]:   27:14.36 Account sync main _request_push(HMOO1, CAPABILITY, {}) = HMOO1
 [imap]:   27:14.36 Account sync main data=HMOO1 CAPABILITY
 [imap]:   27:14.37 Account sync main CAPABILITY:HMOO1.ready.wait
imap.kolabnow.com writer:
 [imap]:   27:14.37 imap.kolabnow.com writer > HMOO1 CAPABILITY\r\n
imap.kolabnow.com reader:
 [imap]:   27:14.41 imap.kolabnow.com reader poll => [(4, 1)]
 [imap]:   27:14.41 imap.kolabnow.com reader rcvd 615
 [imap]:   27:14.41 imap.kolabnow.com reader < * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ ID ENABLE ACL RIGHTS=kxten QUOTA NAMESPACE UIDPLUS NO_ATOMIC_RENAME UNSELECT CHILDREN MULTIAPPEND BINARY CATENATE CONDSTORE ESEARCH SORT SORT=MODSEQ SORT=DISPLAY SORT=UID THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT THREAD=REFERENCES ANNOTATEMORE ANNOTATE-EXPERIMENT-1 LIST-EXTENDED LIST-STATUS LIST-MYRIGHTS WITHIN QRESYNC SCAN XLIST XMOVE MOVE SPECIAL-USE CREATE-SPECIAL-USE URLAUTH URLAUTH=BINARY X-NETSCAPE MUPDATE=mupdate://mupdate.mykolab.com/ AUTH=LOGIN AUTH=PLAIN SASL-IR COMPRESS=DEFLATE X-QUOTA=STORAGE X-QUOTA=MESSAGE X-QUOTA=X-ANNOTATION-STORAGE X-QUOTA=X-NUM-FOLDERS IDLE\r\n
 [imap]:   27:14.41 imap.kolabnow.com reader < HMOO1 OK Completed\r\n
imap.kolabnow.com handler:
 [imap]:   27:14.41 imap.kolabnow.com handler _put_response(* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ ID ENABLE ACL RIGHTS=kxten QUOTA NAMESPACE UIDPLUS NO_ATOMIC_RENAME UNSELECT CHILDREN MULTIAPPEND BINARY CATENATE CONDSTORE ESEARCH SORT SORT=MODSEQ SORT=DISPLAY SORT=UID THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT THREAD=REFERENCES ANNOTATEMORE ANNOTATE-EXPERIMENT-1 LIST-EXTENDED LIST-STATUS LIST-MYRIGHTS WITHIN QRESYNC SCAN XLIST XMOVE MOVE SPECIAL-USE CREATE-SPECIAL-USE URLAUTH URLAUTH=BINARY X-NETSCAPE MUPDATE=mupdate://mupdate.mykolab.com/ AUTH=LOGIN AUTH=PLAIN SASL-IR COMPRESS=DEFLATE X-QUOTA=STORAGE X-QUOTA=MESSAGE X-QUOTA=X-ANNOTATION-STORAGE X-QUOTA=X-NUM-FOLDERS IDLE)
 [imap]:   27:14.41 imap.kolabnow.com handler untagged_responses[CAPABILITY] 1 += ["IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ ID ENABLE ACL RIGHTS=kxten QUOTA NAMESPACE UIDPLUS NO_ATOMIC_RENAME UNSELECT CHILDREN MULTIAPPEND BINARY CATENATE CONDSTORE ESEARCH SORT SORT=MODSEQ SORT=DISPLAY SORT=UID THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT THREAD=REFERENCES ANNOTATEMORE ANNOTATE-EXPERIMENT-1 LIST-EXTENDED LIST-STATUS LIST-MYRIGHTS WITHIN QRESYNC SCAN XLIST XMOVE MOVE SPECIAL-USE CREATE-SPECIAL-USE URLAUTH URLAUTH=BINARY X-NETSCAPE MUPDATE=mupdate://mupdate.mykolab.com/ AUTH=LOGIN AUTH=PLAIN SASL-IR COMPRESS=DEFLATE X-QUOTA=STORAGE X-QUOTA=MESSAGE X-QUOTA=X-ANNOTATION-STORAGE X-QUOTA=X-NUM-FOLDERS IDLE"]
 [imap]:   27:14.41 imap.kolabnow.com handler _put_response(HMOO1 OK Completed)
 [imap]:   27:14.41 imap.kolabnow.com handler state_change_free.set
 [imap]:   27:14.41 imap.kolabnow.com handler _request_pop(HMOO1, ('OK', ['Completed'])) = HMOO1
 [imap]:   27:14.41 imap.kolabnow.com handler CAPABILITY:HMOO1.ready.set
Account sync main:
 [imap]:   27:14.42 Account sync main _get_untagged_response(CAPABILITY) => ['IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ ID ENABLE MUPDATE=mupdate://mupdate.mykolab.com/ AUTH=LOGIN AUTH=PLAIN SASL-IR', 'IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ ID ENABLE ACL RIGHTS=kxten QUOTA NAMESPACE UIDPLUS NO_ATOMIC_RENAME UNSELECT CHILDREN MULTIAPPEND BINARY CATENATE CONDSTORE ESEARCH SORT SORT=MODSEQ SORT=DISPLAY SORT=UID THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT THREAD=REFERENCES ANNOTATEMORE ANNOTATE-EXPERIMENT-1 LIST-EXTENDED LIST-STATUS LIST-MYRIGHTS WITHIN QRESYNC SCAN XLIST XMOVE MOVE SPECIAL-USE CREATE-SPECIAL-USE URLAUTH URLAUTH=BINARY X-NETSCAPE MUPDATE=mupdate://mupdate.mykolab.com/ AUTH=LOGIN AUTH=PLAIN SASL-IR COMPRESS=DEFLATE X-QUOTA=STORAGE X-QUOTA=MESSAGE X-QUOTA=X-ANNOTATION-STORAGE X-QUOTA=X-NUM-FOLDERS IDLE']
 [imap]:   27:14.42 Account sync main _untagged_response(OK, ?, CAPABILITY) => ['IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ ID ENABLE MUPDATE=mupdate://mupdate.mykolab.com/ AUTH=LOGIN AUTH=PLAIN SASL-IR', 'IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ ID ENABLE ACL RIGHTS=kxten QUOTA NAMESPACE UIDPLUS NO_ATOMIC_RENAME UNSELECT CHILDREN MULTIAPPEND BINARY CATENATE CONDSTORE ESEARCH SORT SORT=MODSEQ SORT=DISPLAY SORT=UID THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT THREAD=REFERENCES ANNOTATEMORE ANNOTATE-EXPERIMENT-1 LIST-EXTENDED LIST-STATUS LIST-MYRIGHTS WITHIN QRESYNC SCAN XLIST XMOVE MOVE SPECIAL-USE CREATE-SPECIAL-USE URLAUTH URLAUTH=BINARY X-NETSCAPE MUPDATE=mupdate://mupdate.mykolab.com/ AUTH=LOGIN AUTH=PLAIN SASL-IR COMPRESS=DEFLATE X-QUOTA=STORAGE X-QUOTA=MESSAGE X-QUOTA=X-ANNOTATION-STORAGE X-QUOTA=X-NUM-FOLDERS IDLE']
 [imap]:   27:14.42 Account sync main CAPABILITY: ('IMAP4REV1', 'LITERAL+', 'ID', 'ENABLE', 'ACL', 'RIGHTS=KXTEN', 'QUOTA', 'NAMESPACE', 'UIDPLUS', 'NO_ATOMIC_RENAME', 'UNSELECT', 'CHILDREN', 'MULTIAPPEND', 'BINARY', 'CATENATE', 'CONDSTORE', 'ESEARCH', 'SORT', 'SORT=MODSEQ', 'SORT=DISPLAY', 'SORT=UID', 'THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT', 'THREAD=REFERENCES', 'ANNOTATEMORE', 'ANNOTATE-EXPERIMENT-1', 'LIST-EXTENDED', 'LIST-STATUS', 'LIST-MYRIGHTS', 'WITHIN', 'QRESYNC', 'SCAN', 'XLIST', 'XMOVE', 'MOVE', 'SPECIAL-USE', 'CREATE-SPECIAL-USE', 'URLAUTH', 'URLAUTH=BINARY', 'X-NETSCAPE', 'MUPDATE=MUPDATE://MUPDATE.MYKOLAB.COM/', 'AUTH=LOGIN', 'AUTH=PLAIN', 'SASL-IR', 'COMPRESS=DEFLATE', 'X-QUOTA=STORAGE', 'X-QUOTA=MESSAGE', 'X-QUOTA=X-ANNOTATION-STORAGE', 'X-QUOTA=X-NUM-FOLDERS', 'IDLE')
 [imap]: Attempting PLAIN authentication
 [imap]:   27:14.42 Account sync main [sync] AUTHENTICATE ('PLAIN',)
 [imap]:   27:14.42 Account sync main state_change_pending.acquire
 [imap]:   27:14.42 Account sync main _request_push(HMOO2, AUTHENTICATE, {}) = HMOO2
 [imap]:   27:14.42 Account sync main data=HMOO2 AUTHENTICATE PLAIN
 [imap]:   27:14.42 Account sync main _request_push(continuation, None, {}) = HMOO3
 [imap]:   27:14.42 Account sync main None:HMOO3.ready.wait
imap.kolabnow.com writer:
 [imap]:   27:14.42 imap.kolabnow.com writer > HMOO2 AUTHENTICATE PLAIN\r\n
imap.kolabnow.com reader:
 [imap]:   27:14.47 imap.kolabnow.com reader poll => [(4, 1)]
 [imap]:   27:14.47 imap.kolabnow.com reader rcvd 4
 [imap]:   27:14.47 imap.kolabnow.com reader < + \r\n
imap.kolabnow.com handler:
 [imap]:   27:14.47 imap.kolabnow.com handler _put_response(+ )
 [imap]:   27:14.47 imap.kolabnow.com handler _request_pop(continuation, (True, '')) = HMOO3
 [imap]:   27:14.47 imap.kolabnow.com handler None:HMOO3.ready.set
Account sync main:
 [imap]:   27:14.47 Account sync main continuation => True, 
Enter password for account 'mainRemote': 
 [imap]: __plainhandler: returning bluemorpho@kolabnow.com(passwd)
 [imap]:   27:19.01 Account sync main _request_push(continuation, None, {}) = HMOO4
 [imap]:   27:19.01 Account sync main write literal size 52
 [imap]:   27:19.01 Account sync main None:HMOO4.ready.wait
imap.kolabnow.com writer:
 [imap]:   27:19.01 imap.kolabnow.com writer > AGJsdWVtb3JwaG9Aa29sYWJub3cuY29tAFBoQHN1bDhtYW50NTdE\r\n
imap.kolabnow.com reader:
 [imap]:   27:19.12 imap.kolabnow.com reader poll => [(4, 1)]
 [imap]:   27:19.12 imap.kolabnow.com reader rcvd 684
 [imap]:   27:19.12 imap.kolabnow.com reader < HMOO2 OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ ID ENABLE ACL RIGHTS=kxten QUOTA NAMESPACE UIDPLUS NO_ATOMIC_RENAME UNSELECT CHILDREN MULTIAPPEND BINARY CATENATE CONDSTORE ESEARCH SORT SORT=MODSEQ SORT=DISPLAY SORT=UID THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT THREAD=REFERENCES ANNOTATEMORE ANNOTATE-EXPERIMENT-1 LIST-EXTENDED LIST-STATUS LIST-MYRIGHTS WITHIN QRESYNC SCAN XLIST XMOVE MOVE SPECIAL-USE CREATE-SPECIAL-USE URLAUTH URLAUTH=BINARY X-NETSCAPE MUPDATE=mupdate://mupdate.mykolab.com/ LOGINDISABLED COMPRESS=DEFLATE X-QUOTA=STORAGE X-QUOTA=MESSAGE X-QUOTA=X-ANNOTATION-STORAGE X-QUOTA=X-NUM-FOLDERS IDLE] Success (tls protection) SESSIONID=<imapf01.mykolab.com-22440-1433413633-1-1537824389138375231>\r\n
imap.kolabnow.com handler:
 [imap]:   27:19.12 imap.kolabnow.com handler _put_response(HMOO2 OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ ID ENABLE ACL RIGHTS=kxten QUOTA NAMESPACE UIDPLUS NO_ATOMIC_RENAME UNSELECT CHILDREN MULTIAPPEND BINARY CATENATE CONDSTORE ESEARCH SORT SORT=MODSEQ SORT=DISPLAY SORT=UID THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT THREAD=REFERENCES ANNOTATEMORE ANNOTATE-EXPERIMENT-1 LIST-EXTENDED LIST-STATUS LIST-MYRIGHTS WITHIN QRESYNC SCAN XLIST XMOVE MOVE SPECIAL-USE CREATE-SPECIAL-USE URLAUTH URLAUTH=BINARY X-NETSCAPE MUPDATE=mupdate://mupdate.mykolab.com/ LOGINDISABLED COMPRESS=DEFLATE X-QUOTA=STORAGE X-QUOTA=MESSAGE X-QUOTA=X-ANNOTATION-STORAGE X-QUOTA=X-NUM-FOLDERS IDLE] Success (tls protection) SESSIONID=<imapf01.mykolab.com-22440-1433413633-1-1537824389138375231>)
 [imap]:   27:19.12 imap.kolabnow.com handler untagged_responses[CAPABILITY] 0 += ["IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ ID ENABLE ACL RIGHTS=kxten QUOTA NAMESPACE UIDPLUS NO_ATOMIC_RENAME UNSELECT CHILDREN MULTIAPPEND BINARY CATENATE CONDSTORE ESEARCH SORT SORT=MODSEQ SORT=DISPLAY SORT=UID THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT THREAD=REFERENCES ANNOTATEMORE ANNOTATE-EXPERIMENT-1 LIST-EXTENDED LIST-STATUS LIST-MYRIGHTS WITHIN QRESYNC SCAN XLIST XMOVE MOVE SPECIAL-USE CREATE-SPECIAL-USE URLAUTH URLAUTH=BINARY X-NETSCAPE MUPDATE=mupdate://mupdate.mykolab.com/ LOGINDISABLED COMPRESS=DEFLATE X-QUOTA=STORAGE X-QUOTA=MESSAGE X-QUOTA=X-ANNOTATION-STORAGE X-QUOTA=X-NUM-FOLDERS IDLE"]
 [imap]:   27:19.12 imap.kolabnow.com handler _request_pop(HMOO2, ('OK', ['[CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ ID ENABLE ACL RIGHTS=kxten QUOTA NAMESPACE UIDPLUS NO_ATOMIC_RENAME UNSELECT CHILDREN MULTIAPPEND BINARY CATENATE CONDSTORE ESEARCH SORT SORT=MODSEQ SORT=DISPLAY SORT=UID THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT THREAD=REFERENCES ANNOTATEMORE ANNOTATE-EXPERIMENT-1 LIST-EXTENDED LIST-STATUS LIST-MYRIGHTS WITHIN QRESYNC SCAN XLIST XMOVE MOVE SPECIAL-USE CREATE-SPECIAL-USE URLAUTH URLAUTH=BINARY X-NETSCAPE MUPDATE=mupdate://mupdate.mykolab.com/ LOGINDISABLED COMPRESS=DEFLATE X-QUOTA=STORAGE X-QUOTA=MESSAGE X-QUOTA=X-ANNOTATION-STORAGE X-QUOTA=X-NUM-FOLDERS IDLE] Success (tls protection) SESSIONID=<imapf01.mykolab.com-22440-1433413633-1-1537824389138375231>'])) = HMOO2
 [imap]:   27:19.12 imap.kolabnow.com handler AUTHENTICATE:HMOO2.ready.set
 [imap]:   27:19.12 imap.kolabnow.com handler state_change_free.set
 [imap]:   27:19.12 imap.kolabnow.com handler _request_pop(continuation, (False, 'HMOO2 OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ ID ENABLE ACL RIGHTS=kxten QUOTA NAMESPACE UIDPLUS NO_ATOMIC_RENAME UNSELECT CHILDREN MULTIAPPEND BINARY CATENATE CONDSTORE ESEARCH SORT SORT=MODSEQ SORT=DISPLAY SORT=UID THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT THREAD=REFERENCES ANNOTATEMORE ANNOTATE-EXPERIMENT-1 LIST-EXTENDED LIST-STATUS LIST-MYRIGHTS WITHIN QRESYNC SCAN XLIST XMOVE MOVE SPECIAL-USE CREATE-SPECIAL-USE URLAUTH URLAUTH=BINARY X-NETSCAPE MUPDATE=mupdate://mupdate.mykolab.com/ LOGINDISABLED COMPRESS=DEFLATE X-QUOTA=STORAGE X-QUOTA=MESSAGE X-QUOTA=X-ANNOTATION-STORAGE X-QUOTA=X-NUM-FOLDERS IDLE] Success (tls protection) SESSIONID=<imapf01.mykolab.com-22440-1433413633-1-1537824389138375231>')) = HMOO4
 [imap]:   27:19.12 imap.kolabnow.com handler None:HMOO4.ready.set
Account sync main:
 [imap]:   27:19.12 Account sync main continuation => False, HMOO2 OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ ID ENABLE ACL RIGHTS=kxten QUOTA NAMESPACE UIDPLUS NO_ATOMIC_RENAME UNSELECT CHILDREN MULTIAPPEND BINARY CATENATE CONDSTORE ESEARCH SORT SORT=MODSEQ SORT=DISPLAY SORT=UID THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT THREAD=REFERENCES ANNOTATEMORE ANNOTATE-EXPERIMENT-1 LIST-EXTENDED LIST-STATUS LIST-MYRIGHTS WITHIN QRESYNC SCAN XLIST XMOVE MOVE SPECIAL-USE CREATE-SPECIAL-USE URLAUTH URLAUTH=BINARY X-NETSCAPE MUPDATE=mupdate://mupdate.mykolab.com/ LOGINDISABLED COMPRESS=DEFLATE X-QUOTA=STORAGE X-QUOTA=MESSAGE X-QUOTA=X-ANNOTATION-STORAGE X-QUOTA=X-NUM-FOLDERS IDLE] Success (tls protection) SESSIONID=<imapf01.mykolab.com-22440-1433413633-1-1537824389138375231>
 [imap]:   27:19.12 Account sync main AUTHENTICATE:HMOO2.ready.wait
 [imap]:   27:19.12 Account sync main state => AUTH
 [imap]:   27:19.12 Account sync main state_change_pending.release
 [imap]:   27:19.12 Account sync main [async] CAPABILITY ()
 [imap]:   27:19.12 Account sync main state_change_pending.acquire
 [imap]:   27:19.12 Account sync main state_change_pending.release
 [imap]:   27:19.12 Account sync main _request_push(HMOO5, CAPABILITY, {}) = HMOO5
 [imap]:   27:19.12 Account sync main data=HMOO5 CAPABILITY
 [imap]:   27:19.12 Account sync main CAPABILITY:HMOO5.ready.wait
imap.kolabnow.com writer:
 [imap]:   27:19.12 imap.kolabnow.com writer > HMOO5 CAPABILITY\r\n
imap.kolabnow.com reader:
 [imap]:   27:19.17 imap.kolabnow.com reader poll => [(4, 1)]
 [imap]:   27:19.17 imap.kolabnow.com reader rcvd 599
 [imap]:   27:19.17 imap.kolabnow.com reader < * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ ID ENABLE ACL RIGHTS=kxten QUOTA NAMESPACE UIDPLUS NO_ATOMIC_RENAME UNSELECT CHILDREN MULTIAPPEND BINARY CATENATE CONDSTORE ESEARCH SORT SORT=MODSEQ SORT=DISPLAY SORT=UID THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT THREAD=REFERENCES ANNOTATEMORE ANNOTATE-EXPERIMENT-1 LIST-EXTENDED LIST-STATUS LIST-MYRIGHTS WITHIN QRESYNC SCAN XLIST XMOVE MOVE SPECIAL-USE CREATE-SPECIAL-USE URLAUTH URLAUTH=BINARY X-NETSCAPE MUPDATE=mupdate://mupdate.mykolab.com/ LOGINDISABLED COMPRESS=DEFLATE X-QUOTA=STORAGE X-QUOTA=MESSAGE X-QUOTA=X-ANNOTATION-STORAGE X-QUOTA=X-NUM-FOLDERS IDLE\r\n
 [imap]:   27:19.17 imap.kolabnow.com reader < HMOO5 OK Completed\r\n
imap.kolabnow.com handler:
 [imap]:   27:19.17 imap.kolabnow.com handler _put_response(* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ ID ENABLE ACL RIGHTS=kxten QUOTA NAMESPACE UIDPLUS NO_ATOMIC_RENAME UNSELECT CHILDREN MULTIAPPEND BINARY CATENATE CONDSTORE ESEARCH SORT SORT=MODSEQ SORT=DISPLAY SORT=UID THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT THREAD=REFERENCES ANNOTATEMORE ANNOTATE-EXPERIMENT-1 LIST-EXTENDED LIST-STATUS LIST-MYRIGHTS WITHIN QRESYNC SCAN XLIST XMOVE MOVE SPECIAL-USE CREATE-SPECIAL-USE URLAUTH URLAUTH=BINARY X-NETSCAPE MUPDATE=mupdate://mupdate.mykolab.com/ LOGINDISABLED COMPRESS=DEFLATE X-QUOTA=STORAGE X-QUOTA=MESSAGE X-QUOTA=X-ANNOTATION-STORAGE X-QUOTA=X-NUM-FOLDERS IDLE)
 [imap]:   27:19.17 imap.kolabnow.com handler untagged_responses[CAPABILITY] 1 += ["IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ ID ENABLE ACL RIGHTS=kxten QUOTA NAMESPACE UIDPLUS NO_ATOMIC_RENAME UNSELECT CHILDREN MULTIAPPEND BINARY CATENATE CONDSTORE ESEARCH SORT SORT=MODSEQ SORT=DISPLAY SORT=UID THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT THREAD=REFERENCES ANNOTATEMORE ANNOTATE-EXPERIMENT-1 LIST-EXTENDED LIST-STATUS LIST-MYRIGHTS WITHIN QRESYNC SCAN XLIST XMOVE MOVE SPECIAL-USE CREATE-SPECIAL-USE URLAUTH URLAUTH=BINARY X-NETSCAPE MUPDATE=mupdate://mupdate.mykolab.com/ LOGINDISABLED COMPRESS=DEFLATE X-QUOTA=STORAGE X-QUOTA=MESSAGE X-QUOTA=X-ANNOTATION-STORAGE X-QUOTA=X-NUM-FOLDERS IDLE"]
 [imap]:   27:19.17 imap.kolabnow.com handler _put_response(HMOO5 OK Completed)
 [imap]:   27:19.17 imap.kolabnow.com handler state_change_free.set
 [imap]:   27:19.17 imap.kolabnow.com handler _request_pop(HMOO5, ('OK', ['Completed'])) = HMOO5
 [imap]:   27:19.17 imap.kolabnow.com handler CAPABILITY:HMOO5.ready.set
Account sync main:
 [imap]:   27:19.18 Account sync main _get_untagged_response(CAPABILITY) => ['IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ ID ENABLE ACL RIGHTS=kxten QUOTA NAMESPACE UIDPLUS NO_ATOMIC_RENAME UNSELECT CHILDREN MULTIAPPEND BINARY CATENATE CONDSTORE ESEARCH SORT SORT=MODSEQ SORT=DISPLAY SORT=UID THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT THREAD=REFERENCES ANNOTATEMORE ANNOTATE-EXPERIMENT-1 LIST-EXTENDED LIST-STATUS LIST-MYRIGHTS WITHIN QRESYNC SCAN XLIST XMOVE MOVE SPECIAL-USE CREATE-SPECIAL-USE URLAUTH URLAUTH=BINARY X-NETSCAPE MUPDATE=mupdate://mupdate.mykolab.com/ LOGINDISABLED COMPRESS=DEFLATE X-QUOTA=STORAGE X-QUOTA=MESSAGE X-QUOTA=X-ANNOTATION-STORAGE X-QUOTA=X-NUM-FOLDERS IDLE', 'IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ ID ENABLE ACL RIGHTS=kxten QUOTA NAMESPACE UIDPLUS NO_ATOMIC_RENAME UNSELECT CHILDREN MULTIAPPEND BINARY CATENATE CONDSTORE ESEARCH SORT SORT=MODSEQ SORT=DISPLAY SORT=UID THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT THREAD=REFERENCES ANNOTATEMORE ANNOTATE-EXPERIMENT-1 LIST-EXTENDED LIST-STATUS LIST-MYRIGHTS WITHIN QRESYNC SCAN XLIST XMOVE MOVE SPECIAL-USE CREATE-SPECIAL-USE URLAUTH URLAUTH=BINARY X-NETSCAPE MUPDATE=mupdate://mupdate.mykolab.com/ LOGINDISABLED COMPRESS=DEFLATE X-QUOTA=STORAGE X-QUOTA=MESSAGE X-QUOTA=X-ANNOTATION-STORAGE X-QUOTA=X-NUM-FOLDERS IDLE']
 [imap]:   27:19.18 Account sync main _untagged_response(OK, ?, CAPABILITY) => ['IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ ID ENABLE ACL RIGHTS=kxten QUOTA NAMESPACE UIDPLUS NO_ATOMIC_RENAME UNSELECT CHILDREN MULTIAPPEND BINARY CATENATE CONDSTORE ESEARCH SORT SORT=MODSEQ SORT=DISPLAY SORT=UID THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT THREAD=REFERENCES ANNOTATEMORE ANNOTATE-EXPERIMENT-1 LIST-EXTENDED LIST-STATUS LIST-MYRIGHTS WITHIN QRESYNC SCAN XLIST XMOVE MOVE SPECIAL-USE CREATE-SPECIAL-USE URLAUTH URLAUTH=BINARY X-NETSCAPE MUPDATE=mupdate://mupdate.mykolab.com/ LOGINDISABLED COMPRESS=DEFLATE X-QUOTA=STORAGE X-QUOTA=MESSAGE X-QUOTA=X-ANNOTATION-STORAGE X-QUOTA=X-NUM-FOLDERS IDLE', 'IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ ID ENABLE ACL RIGHTS=kxten QUOTA NAMESPACE UIDPLUS NO_ATOMIC_RENAME UNSELECT CHILDREN MULTIAPPEND BINARY CATENATE CONDSTORE ESEARCH SORT SORT=MODSEQ SORT=DISPLAY SORT=UID THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT THREAD=REFERENCES ANNOTATEMORE ANNOTATE-EXPERIMENT-1 LIST-EXTENDED LIST-STATUS LIST-MYRIGHTS WITHIN QRESYNC SCAN XLIST XMOVE MOVE SPECIAL-USE CREATE-SPECIAL-USE URLAUTH URLAUTH=BINARY X-NETSCAPE MUPDATE=mupdate://mupdate.mykolab.com/ LOGINDISABLED COMPRESS=DEFLATE X-QUOTA=STORAGE X-QUOTA=MESSAGE X-QUOTA=X-ANNOTATION-STORAGE X-QUOTA=X-NUM-FOLDERS IDLE']
 [imap]:   27:19.18 Account sync main [async] LIST ('', '""')
 [imap]:   27:19.18 Account sync main state_change_pending.acquire
 [imap]:   27:19.18 Account sync main state_change_pending.release
 [imap]:   27:19.18 Account sync main _request_push(HMOO6, LIST, {}) = HMOO6
 [imap]:   27:19.18 Account sync main data=HMOO6 LIST "" ""
 [imap]:   27:19.18 Account sync main LIST:HMOO6.ready.wait
imap.kolabnow.com writer:
 [imap]:   27:19.18 imap.kolabnow.com writer > HMOO6 LIST "" ""\r\n
imap.kolabnow.com reader:
 [imap]:   27:19.23 imap.kolabnow.com reader poll => [(4, 1)]
 [imap]:   27:19.23 imap.kolabnow.com reader rcvd 60
 [imap]:   27:19.23 imap.kolabnow.com reader < * LIST (\Noselect) "/" ""\r\n
 [imap]:   27:19.23 imap.kolabnow.com reader < HMOO6 OK Completed (0.000 secs)\r\n
imap.kolabnow.com handler:
 [imap]:   27:19.23 imap.kolabnow.com handler _put_response(* LIST (\Noselect) "/" "")
 [imap]:   27:19.23 imap.kolabnow.com handler untagged_responses[LIST] 0 += ["(\Noselect) "/" """]
 [imap]:   27:19.23 imap.kolabnow.com handler _put_response(HMOO6 OK Completed (0.000 secs))
 [imap]:   27:19.23 imap.kolabnow.com handler state_change_free.set
 [imap]:   27:19.23 imap.kolabnow.com handler _request_pop(HMOO6, ('OK', ['Completed (0.000 secs)'])) = HMOO6
 [imap]:   27:19.23 imap.kolabnow.com handler LIST:HMOO6.ready.set
Account sync main:
 [imap]:   27:19.23 Account sync main _get_untagged_response(LIST) => ['(\\Noselect) "/" ""']
 [imap]:   27:19.23 Account sync main _untagged_response(OK, ?, LIST) => ['(\\Noselect) "/" ""']
 [imap]:   27:19.23 Account sync main [async] LIST ('', '*')
 [imap]:   27:19.23 Account sync main state_change_pending.acquire
 [imap]:   27:19.23 Account sync main state_change_pending.release
 [imap]:   27:19.23 Account sync main _request_push(HMOO7, LIST, {}) = HMOO7
 [imap]:   27:19.24 Account sync main data=HMOO7 LIST "" "*"
 [imap]:   27:19.24 Account sync main LIST:HMOO7.ready.wait
imap.kolabnow.com writer:
 [imap]:   27:19.24 imap.kolabnow.com writer > HMOO7 LIST "" "*"\r\n
imap.kolabnow.com reader:
 [imap]:   27:19.29 imap.kolabnow.com reader poll => [(4, 1)]
 [imap]:   27:19.29 imap.kolabnow.com reader rcvd 33
 [imap]:   27:19.29 imap.kolabnow.com reader < HMOO7 OK Completed (0.000 secs)\r\n
imap.kolabnow.com handler:
 [imap]:   27:19.29 imap.kolabnow.com handler _put_response(HMOO7 OK Completed (0.000 secs))
 [imap]:   27:19.29 imap.kolabnow.com handler state_change_free.set
 [imap]:   27:19.29 imap.kolabnow.com handler _request_pop(HMOO7, ('OK', ['Completed (0.000 secs)'])) = HMOO7
 [imap]:   27:19.30 imap.kolabnow.com handler LIST:HMOO7.ready.set
Account sync main:
 []: Copying folder structure from mainRemote to mainLocal
 *** Finished account 'main' in 0:06
```

**EDIT2**: BTW, i use fedora 22.

Comment: You could try turning on debugging for IMAP (`-d imap`) and check what happens there. Especially interesting would be the response to the `LIST` command, which is supposed to list all the folders on the remote side.

Comment: ´LIST ('', '""')` and ´LIST "" ""\r\n` seems to have no value, right?